# Windows 10 System Image Restore Failed - The Parameter is Incorrect

Tags: windows-10, backup

I backed up my computer by using Windows Backup and Recovery System Image.  I have been using this technique for years with windows 7, 8 and 8.1.  I use a System Repair disc to successfully restore image copies when necessary.

So I upgraded to Windows 10 and was able to make a new repair disc.

I made an image copy under Windows 10 and went to test the ability to recover using the Windows 10 system repair disc.  The recovery seemed to be going fine, then at the end I get a message that the restore failed due to "The Parameter is Incorrect (0x80070057)".  That wiped out my drive and all I could do was restore back to Windows 8.1 from a different backup and recovery set.

Any idea what causes this and how to fix it in Windows 10?  I have seen posts for Windows 7 and 8, but they don't directly relate to my experience.

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of is if you created the recovery set while at build 10240 but attempted to restore it while using Version 1511.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution? I was just moving data to a new SSD so I didn't lose anything but worry about next time.

Comment: I just started using AOMEI backupper instead. It was a pain to restore Windows but since then I haven't had problems.